# how change wallpaper on Windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-mobile

I get SBC's WinCE 5.0 closed image,
how change wallpaper on Windows CE 5.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do on a PC, Right Click on the Desktop, Properties, Background, Browse. Its also easy to change it in the registry if you have an editor or remote tool.